# Ubuntu Bootloader 16.04

Tags: dual-boot, grub2

I removed all of my disks except one and installed Ubuntu. I plugged all my disks back and no problem. I selected Ubuntu from BIOS. Fast load and shut down. However, I tried a couple of apps and got broken instances that I could not fix and then I couldn't run all the updates.

I re-installed Ubuntu using the same procedure but now after installing I run all of the updates (4  of them apparently did not go through). That is the only difference between my first and second installs. I plugged all of my disks back and I am not sure at what point but then I realize that when picking Ubuntu disk from BIOS now it brings a Boot loader with Windows 10 and Windows 7 on it which both are in separate disks with their on boot loaders. Also shut down now takes a reasonable amount of time.

In both cases both installations were fresh with not many modifications with the exception of all of the updates on the second one.

How did this happen? Can Ubuntu create boot loaders by itself?
Is Ubuntu looking at new partitions or disks for another OS?
Was this a product of all of the updates after my re-installation?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

*How did this happen? Can Ubuntu create boot loaders by itself?*

Ubuntu includes, installs and uses [GRUB](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/Grub2), a bootloader.

*Is Ubuntu looking at new partitions or disks for another OS?*

GRUB is, that's what is does.

*Was this a product of all of the updates after my re-installation?*

Yes and No... It was triggered by one update (kernel) but it would have happened anyway had you had your additional partitions (Windows) connected during the installation.

Everything you describe is what should happen and what so many users fail to achieve for one reason or another when dual-booting with Windows 8 or 10.
Please read the link above about GRUB for detailed in depth information. For using all you need to know is that GRUB will chainload all the other OSes bootloaders and give you an additional way to select the other OSes even when you select Ubuntu from the UEFI Boot Menu.

Comment: I also disabled the 3 disks from BIOS left just one for Ubuntu but W7 and W10 were still listed. I did not try to boot from any option but if this is a dynamic process I would have thought that by inactivating the disks from BIOS  will immediately remove those options from the boot loader.

Comment: It isn't dynamic. The os-prober will check again when a new kernel version is installed and adjust for the new configuration. You can do it also with `sudo update-grub`.